# Coverting same named function into single function using cascading in Java

Tags: java

Is there any way to convert below function into one function in Java ? I tried cascading it using (TestRow ) but that doesn't work.

```
public void testWindow (TestRow window, String title) {
    if (window != null) {
        try {
            window.zClose(window);
        } catch (HarnessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        window = null;
    }
}

public void testWindow (TestColumn window, String title) {
    if (window != null) {
        try {
            window.zClose(window);
        } catch (HarnessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        window = null;
    }
}
```

Here TestRow and TestColumn is custom types.

Calling would be same way but due to custom window names, i need to copy paste same function many times which i think can be avoidable.

Comment: Do `TestColumn` and `TestRow` have common interface / abstract class to which method `zClose` belongs?

Comment: How can we know the implementation of zClose()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract your common logic in a separate method with common windows class as a parameter and call this common method in many places. E.g.

```
public void testWindow (TestRow window, String title) {
    closeWindow(window);
}

public void testWindow (TestColumn window, String title) {
    closeWindow(window);
}

private void closeWindow(CommonWindowsClass window) {
    if (window != null) {
        try {
            window.zClose(window);
        } catch (HarnessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        window = null;
    }
}
```

Here `CommonWindowsClass` is superclass both for `TestRow` and `TestColumn` classes.

**UPDATE** also I suppose you actually don't need this code line `window = null;` at all

Comment: Thanks Andriy for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use inheritance. Something like:

```
public abstract class Test {
    public abstract void zClose( Teste t );
}

public class TestRow extends Test {
    @Override
    public void zClose( Test t ) {
         // code...
    }
}

public class TestColumn extends Test {
    @Override
    public void zClose( Test t ) {
         // code...
    }
}

public void testWindow (Test window, String title) {
    if (window != null) {
        try {
            window.zClose(window);
        } catch (HarnessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        window = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David for the help!